# What is the Stack Overflow Constitution?

Tags: support, podcast, constitution-amendment

The "Stack Overflow Constitution" was introduced in [Stack Overflow Podcast #88](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/09/26/podcast-88-all-about-documentation-mostly/).

> A big change to pay close attention to: We’re writing the Stack Overflow Constitution, and we’re asking you, our listeners, to vote on the various elements of this new pivotal document.

Each week, a new amendment is proposed, listeners are asked to comment and vote on them via Twitter (#StackOverflowPodcast), and a winning answer is chosen.

There hasn't previously been a list of all the constitutional amendments and the winning responses, but there is now. The wiki post below can be updated as new amendments are added.

Comment: Does anyone else think it's weird that this "document" is composed entirely of amendments? What do they amend?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Most US history classes make the students learn about each of the amendments, even some make the students memorize what each amendment did. But very rarely does the class require the student to even read the US Constitution. Composing the SO Constitution entirely of ammendments could either be a mockery of that failure or a result of that culture.

Comment: @DavyM then that is a failure of out f-ed up education system in which the lowest common denominator gets preference. When I was in school, we did learn about the constitution itself before the bill of rights

Comment: @psubsee2003 To whom are you referring when you say the lowest common denominator gets preference?

Comment: Isn't this where you pledge allegiance to Joel Spolsky, and to the Meta, in which he takes stands?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Amendment 1

> Socks go on before pants or pants before socks?

Con. I tried to put socks on before pants but got an InvalidOperationException. – Bryan Bedard

#### Amendment 2

> Should programming languages count toward your college language requirement?

My request was denied, so I got to learn a little French instead. – Michael Berkowski

#### Amendment 3

> When you are at the supermarket, should you be able to eat an item BEFORE you get to the cash register?

Pro, the only problem is fitting on the scales after snacking by the bulk bins. – Jonathan Lisic

#### Amendment 4

> Are you allowed to stand over the IT person while you wait for them to reset your password?

#### Amendment 5

> Do you hold the door for a colleague if you know it’s going to make them run?

Pro. Not only am I being polite, I’m helping improve their health. – Andrew Bickerton

#### Amendment 6

> If somebody drops a scrap of paper on the subway and they don’t notice, do you tell them?

#### Amendment 7

> Should you be allowed to comment out code and check it in?

CON, this dark road leads to being featured on an episode of 'Hoarders.' – @Joe_Stetch

#### Amendment 8

> Is it ok to get a mechanical keyboard with loud "clicky" keys when you are sharing an office?

PRO because they shouldn’t be able to hear the keyboard over my trap music.
– @TheBestHuman

#### Amendment 9

> Is it pronounced GIF with a hard G /ɡif/ or GIF with a J /jif/?

I like my Gifs with a hard G, because I refuse to unwrap Jifts at Christmas. – @AgileStCyr

#### Amendment 10

> Shall we bring back [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)?

YAY but only the real Hungarian notation. Semantics based instead of type based. In Hungarian instead of English. – @inka22222

#### Amendment 11

> Is it sufficient to close a bug as NOT REPRO or do you have to write some kind of explanation?

Always explain… that’s the point of SO after all. – @racascou

#### Amendment 12

> Is it grammatically correct to say "Data is…" or "Data are…"?

CON because it’s weird to say "Data are my favorite Star Trek character" – @ethanjpeters

#### Amendment 13

> When driving with a friend, is it ok to ask that friend to get out and direct you while parallel parking?

I reach out for help
You guide me to safe landing
Social bonds are built
– @HaikusByIsaac

#### Amendment 14

> If you switch back and forth between Macintosh and Windows should you remap COMMAND to be ALT and vice versa?

CON. We CTRL our minds to adapt to the ALT keyboard layouts since there is no ESC from other machines in the world. – Daniel Allan White

#### Amendment 15

> Should you have a 50 character max for the first line of your commit message?

PRO: because 50 characters should be enough if you're – Tzach Zohar

#### Amendment 16

> If you are making a sandwich for yourself, do you cut it in half?

PRO All bread products taste better when cut diagonally. True for sandwiches, toast and especially bagels. – Andrew Wilkinson

#### Amendment 17

> If you’re writing an IF statement, and you’re comparing a variable to a constant, should you flip it so that you put the constant first?

PRO Be always careful we must, but only a Sith deals with absolutes. Also easier to read it becomes. – Victor Villas

#### Amendment 18

> When you say that you are going to "table" a topic, does that mean that you are going to talk about it now, or that you are not going to talk about it at all?

Pro. Thanks for chairing this poll about tabling. I'm sure I will be floored by the results. – Tom Eldridge

#### Amendment 19

> When replying to an email, you cannot reply inline. You must always add your reply above the quoted text.

```
Asger‏ @oddswithreality
Replying to @HaikusByIsaac @StackPodcast and 6 others
INLINE
>> ... CON ...
>That's got my vote.
PRO IS MINE
>>... you *cannot* reply inline ...
>This is clearly false.
 
Haikus by Isaac‏ @HaikusByIsaac
>>> ... CON ...
>>That's got my vote.
> PRO IS MINE
Of course it is,
Eponymously!
```

[View on Twitter](https://twitter.com/HaikusByIsaac/status/857236064334905344)

#### Amendment 20

> On what day of the week does ‘this weekend’ and ‘next weekend’ mean something different?

CON - In JS it would be: `isWeekEnd() ? next = following_occurance : next = this ; isWeekEnd() ? this = current : this = next ;` – Timothy Birrell

#### Amendment 21

> Should you throw away the sub-liner on yogurt and hummus containers?

CON: not because the liner offers protection; because I'm too lazy to take it to the trash right away. - Ru Cindrea

#### Amendment 22

> If you live in a touristy city, like NYC, is it rude to say "no" if someone asks you to take a picture of them?

PRO. But use your own camera, thank them, and walk off. – Tim Wright

#### Amendment 23

> If I say "June 1st at midnight," am I referring to the morning of June 1st or the evening?

PRO: at midnight on Jan 1st 0000 it was officially decided that the last second of the day is 11:59:59: – Ari Porad

#### Amendment 24

> Is it okay to throw things in other people's trash cans when walking down a row of cubicles? PRO for yes, CON for ew, no.

CON don't use their trash can, leave it on their desk. One mans trash is another mans treasure. – Sharshiel Borisute

#### Amendment 25

> In markdown, when adding to the middle of a numbered list, do you fix the subsequent numbers? Answer with PRO if you must correct the numbers, or CON if you think “Why bother? The syntax will straighten itself out."

1. Add your list item
2. Fix all the other items
3. Vote PRO
4. Realize that you’re a good person

– Ari Porad

#### Amendment 26

> When reading code, would you pronounce the parentheses in a function call as "bananas"? PRO = Yes, I would call them bananas; CON = No, Jason Punyon is bananas.

Er what? CON.
Bananas: 
Parens: ()
One makes bread, the other makes LISP. Can't you tell the difference?
– Monica Cellio

#### Amendment 27

> When commenting code, comments should be inline, instead of above the line.

CON: Requiring all comments to be in-line is out of line.  – (((Nat Knight)))

#### Amendment 28

> Is an OS background process (“D-A-E-M-O-N”) pronounced “demon” or “damon”?
> Post PRO if you pronounce it "DEE-mon", or CON if you pronounce it "DAY-mon".

DEE-mon. 2 reasons:

1. Most of them are evil.
2. Damons cost a lot of money and time to save, see: so many movies.

– Nick Craver

#### Amendment 29

> Is it ok to take your shoes off at the office?
> Pro: Take 'em off!  CON: Shoes are required

PRO : but remember, barefooters (like atheists) ain’t got no soul! – Sean Ennis

#### Amendment 30

> In line at the supermarket, which customer is responsible for placing the divider bar between items?
> PRO is the person in front should do it and CON is the person in back should.

Con, there's no such thing as a free lunch. – Corey Beaumont

#### Amendment 31

> When working in git, one must always use rebasing instead of merging branches.
> Post PRO if you prefer rebasing over merge and CON if its merge over rebasing all the way.

CON: Those who edit their git history are doomed to repeat it – @TheOnlyMego

#### Amendment 32

> It is forbidden to participate in a Hangout or other video conference while working at a treadmill desk or any other form of treadmill.
> Post PRO if you think that treadmill desks should be banned when in a video call or CON if you think that exercising while in a meeting is fair game.

PRO! Unless the treadmill-er falls with great hilarity, in which case their behaviour is permitted. – @toonarmycaptain

#### Amendment 33

> Candy Corn: PRO or CON?
> Post PRO if you think that candy corn is delicious or CON if you think they are disgusting and no one should eat them ever.

PRO Because to support corn, in all its forms, is what it means to be American. – Adam Richeimer

#### Amendment 34

> Khan (full name “Khan Noonien Singh”) was the best villain on Star Trek:
> Pro: Khan
> Con: Not Khan

Pro: only Khan Khan do the Khan Khan – Mordechai Zuber

#### Amendment 35

> Eggnog? Is it delicious? Is it even food?